# Can't obtain a JSF @ManagedBean @ViewScoped bean from HttpSession object

Tags: jsf

I need to access my `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` bean from a servlet for getting some information to a javascript via http get request.

```java
package com.test.web.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.text.web.beans.BeanController;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "contactbean")
public class ContactBean extends BeanController implements Serializable {

    // variables

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
         // init
    }

}
```

Code in the servlet of the method that obtains beans from HttpSession

```java
private <T> T retrieveBean(String beanName, HttpSession session) {

        Map map = (Map) session.getAttribute("com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps");

        for (Object entry : map.values()) {
            if (entry instanceof Map) {
                Map viewScopes = (Map) entry;
                if (viewScopes.containsKey(beanName)) {
                    return (T) viewScopes.get(beanName);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I got opened corresponding page — the bean gets initialized. Then I send GET request to the servlet, and look at debugger. The `com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps` map from `HttpSession` object contains all the others `@ViewScoped` beans, but not the one I need.

Any ideas why it can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem — `p:remoteCommand` component. It allows you trigger javascript from beans. So now it isn't necessary to pass values from beans to javascript, you can check according values in the bean inside, and trigger javascript with `PrimeFaces.current().executeScript()`